# Ubuntu 14.04 - HP Stream 11 touchpad stopped working after system update

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, hp, stream

I just got an HP Stream 11 it came with windows but I decided to wipe the disc and install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. At first the WIFI wasn't working and after hours of trying, I finally got it working. At that time the touchpad was working just fine. When I got the WIFI working the software updater suggested to do some updates and I clicked install.

After the installation was done I rebooted the laptop as asked and when it turned back on the touchpad was not working. If I connect a mouse via USB I can still use the laptop but it's not an ideal situation.

So far I've tried a lot of possible solutions that I have found on the internet but nothing has worked.

I tried doing xinput list and the touchpad does not appear in the list nor does an input with Synaptics in the name which could also be the touch pad.

I am very new to Ubuntu so I don't know very well what information could be of use to you to help me.

I've read that if the input does not appear doing xinput then it's probably a kernel issue and that all I can do is report the bug and wait for an update that could possibly fix it.

Just in case I am still writing cause I need a solution asap, I bought this laptop for college and having to use it always with a mouse kind of ruins it's portability.

Thanks a lot in advance and if you need more information just tell me how to get it and I will post it back here so you can have a better idea of what is happening.

Comment: You should look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/741661/touchpad-wont-work-after-kernel-update/748995#748995, which cover a similar (maybe the same) issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue. For now, when you boot, you can hold down the shift key and it should show you the grub bootloader menu. Go to advanced options and choose the older kernel, it will boot and you will be back to normal, as if you hadn't updated. You can set grub to default to that kernel by editing /etc/default/grub